# how to merge array to a multi array as key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

```
 var r = {},
 i,
    keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    values = ['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e',' f'];

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    r[keys[i]] = values[i];
}

console.log(r);
```

Im just getting this error from my console.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target

This is the output i want to get.

```
{
  "one": "a",
  "two": "b",
  "three": "c"
},
{
  "one": "d",
  "two": "e",
  "three": "f"
}
```

Comment: Neither the input nor the output is valid.

Comment: whhat is `values = ['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e',' f'];` is suppossed to be ?

Comment: The output `r` is declared as an object (`{}`). This means it needs to have a key-value pair as its contents. The expected output are two separate objects (each with 3 key-value pairs). May be you need two outputs like `r1` and `r2` - each an object? Or, you need the output to be an array of objects. Please clarify. BTW, `values` also does not seem to be valid format. Does it need to be `values = [['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e',' f']];` --> ie, array of arrays?

Comment: i have tried to use the  values = ['a', 'b', 'c'] to only get the output r = { "one": "a",
  "two": "b",
  "three": "c"}. I just want to append the keys in the other array.

Comment: If you use: `const keys=['one', 'two', 'three'], values=[['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e',' f']];`, then try this: `console.log(values.map(ar => ar.reduce((t, v, i) => ({...t, [keys[i]] : v}), {})));` and share your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The main destructuring error occurs because you have an invalid `values` assignment, I added some square brackets around the two arrays to fix that.

```js
let keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'],
 values = [['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e',' f']];
    
let r = values.map(v => 
  Object.fromEntries(
    keys.map((k, i) => ([k, v[i]]))
  )
);

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer that i wanted.